# WCF Service Library endpoint not found with POST

Tags: wcf, http, post

I am trying to POST some JSON data to a WCF Service Library.

I created a `GettingStartedLib` service interface:

```
namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface IService
    {
        //[OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string EchoWithGet(string s);

        //[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "EchoWithPost")]
        string EchoWithPost(Person person);
    }
}
```

And a service implementation class:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string EchoWithGet(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }

    public string EchoWithPost(Person p)
    {
        return "You said " + p.ToString();
    }
}
```

And a Host

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String home = "http://localhost/services/";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(home));

        try
        {
            ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            host.Open();

            using (ChannelFactory<IService> cf = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new WebHttpBinding(), home))
            {
                cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

                IService channel = cf.CreateChannel();

                // Get works fine
                s = channel.EchoWithGet("Hello, world. GETGET");

                // Discarded. Changing to HTTP
                // s = channel.EchoWithPost({"FirstName": "Anthony"});
          }

          Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate");
          Console.ReadLine();

          host.Close();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException cex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", cex.Message);
        host.Abort();
    }
}
```

And a `Person` class:

```
namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a HTTP page client

```
$.post("localhost/services/EchoWithPost",
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/services/EchoWithPost",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "FirstName": "Anthony" }
}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And my network preview returns an error:

> Endpoint Not found

The `App.config` for the services class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="GettingStartedLib.Service">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost/services/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="GettingStartedLib.IService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I search for TraceSVCViewer and added the code for it. There is a Process error log

```
The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. 
The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. 
This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. 
See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/EchoWithPost")]
string EchoWithPost(Person person);

 <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />    
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="GettingStartedLib.Service">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "http://localhost/services/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="GettingStartedLib.IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Same result. the recieved data is 'RAW', expected 'Json/XML'

Comment: I added svc viewer log and see.
The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.
Now I am trying to disable the log to see endpoint error

Comment: You must use WCF? This task will be trivial with ASP.NET MVC WebApi, ckeck this tutorial anyway: http://dotnetmentors.com/wcf/how-to-create-wcf-restful-services.aspx

Comment: Oh I get trousble to disable the svc viewer. I just want to create a web service that receive POST data and return a json. It is better to choose the WCF Application project template?

Comment: WCF is not the best solution for REST service IMHO, I would go for ASP.NET MVC Web API, you can achieve this in less than 10 minutes, literally: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaoAYo4BnRc

Comment: Thanks Isma C. I better move the the updatest MVC Web API